# convert enhanced for loop to for loop

Tags: java

how to convert this 'enhanced for loop' below to 'for loop'

```
ArrayList<Integer> input= new ArrayList<Integer>();

int[] copies = new int[20];
 for(int allCopies : input) {
        copies[allCopies]++;
    }
```

we've tried this:

```
for(int k = 0; k < input.size(); k++) {
```

for this part:

```
for(int allCopies : input) {
```

but we don't know how to get this part:

```
copies[allCopies]++;
```

any HELP?????

Comment: copies[input.get(k)]++;

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<Integer> input= new ArrayList<Integer>();

int[] copies = new int[20];
for(int k = 0; k < input.size(); k++) {
    copies[input.get(k)]++;
}
```

In an enhanced for loop `for(int allCopies : input)`

`allCopies` is the same as `input[counterPosition]`.

So basically all this is doing is getting that value using `k` as the counter.

`input.get(k)`

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
int allCopies = input.get(k);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
copies[input.get(k)]++;
```

You should look at the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) first to find the appropriate method to use.