# Converting an enhanced for loop to a regular for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

```
for (String title : titles)
{
     // Code
}
```

If I were to convert that to a for loop that looked like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i ++)
```

How would it look like?

Comment: What is `titles`?  How is it defined?

Comment: It would look ... just like that.

Comment: Is `titles` an array?  A list of some kind?  Or some other kind of collection?

Comment: Well, maybe you need to find out, otherwise nobody can give you the code.

Comment: Ok, what I want is the for loop in part B http://www.skylit.com/beprepared/x2013a1.html

Comment: OK, see at the top where it says `List titles` inside the parentheses?  That answers my question about whether `titles` is an array, a list or something else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405706/convert-enhanced-for-loop-to-for-loop?rq=1 among probably a dozen others

Comment: @BrianRoach - Haha.  If my sister looked like Cindy Crawford, what would she look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that `titles` is a `List<String>`, which is implied by the comments below the question.

```
for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
    String title = titles.get(i);
    //Do something with title
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I will accept as right answer in 9 minutes. :)

Answer (score 2):

If "titles" is an array (indicated by []):

```
for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    String title = titles[i];
    //code here
}
```

If "titles" is a List:

```
for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
    String title = titles.get(i);
    //code here
}
```